How to save page content to pdf by xamarin android platform
am using xamarin to create android app, I want to generate page to pdf, in another words the page is like a report i want to take a snapshot for this report then converting it to pdf file.
i tried gembox.pdf but i didn't know how to add the page, it was creating an empty pdf
